# Traefik 404 error using internal-network docker

Tags: docker, https, keycloak, traefik

I'm trying to understand why I get a 404 error. I have reduced it down to docker-compose networks, but still unable to figure out Traefik.

This docker compose returns a 404 error.

```
version: '3'

networks:
  # keycloak_network:
  #   driver: bridge
  web:
    external: true 
  internal-network:
    internal: true

volumes:
  keycloak_data:
      driver: local

services:
  keycloak_postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - keycloak_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
        POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      restart: always
      networks:
      # keycloak_network:
        web:
  keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak
      #build: ./server 
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: ${DB_VENDOR}
        DB_ADDR: ${DB_ADDR}
        POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
        DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
        DB_SCHEMA: ${DB_SCHEMA}
        DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        KEYCLOAK_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_USER}
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
        #PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
        # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
        #JDBC_PARAMS: "ssl=true"
      depends_on:
        - keycloak_postgres
      volumes:
        - ./themes:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/custom_theme
        - ./disable_ssl.sh:/opt/jboss/keycloak/disable_ssl.sh
        - ./themes/base/account/account.ftl:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/base/account/account.ftl
        #- ./nginx/ssl:/etc/x509/https
      restart: always
      networks:
        #keycloak_network:
        web:
          # aliases:
          #  - "api.adwin.usa.northeast.dn"
      ports:
        - "8444:8080"
      logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
         max-size: "200k"
         max-file: "10"
      labels:
        - traefik.port=8080
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Path:/keycloak
        - traefik.docker.network=web
        #- traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.adwin.usa.northeast.dn
        #- traefik.frontend.rule=Path:/keycloak




  omgwtfssl:
   image: paulczar/omgwtfssl
   volumes:
    - "./certs:/certs"
   environment:
    - SSL_SUBJECT=*



  keycloak_graphql:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.0.0-alpha40
    # ports:
    #   - "9091:8080"
    depends_on:
      - "keycloak_postgres"
      - "keycloak_auth"
    restart: always
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${DB_ADDR}:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_TELEMETRY: "false" # https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/guides/telemetry.html
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: ${HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET}
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_AUTH_HOOK: ${HASURA_GRAPHQL_AUTH_HOOK}
    networks:
      #keycloak_network:
      web:
    labels:
      - traefik.port=8080
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Path:/keycloak-graphql
      - traefik.docker.network=web
      #- traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.adwin.usa.northeast.dn
  keycloak_auth:
    image: httpsomkar/keycloak-hasura-connector:latest
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID: ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID}
      KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL: ${KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL}
      KEYCLOAK_REALM: ${KEYCLOAK_REALM}
      KEYCLOAK_SECRET: ${KEYCLOAK_SECRET}
      AUTH_MODE: ${AUTH_MODE} # SINGLE USER, ORGANIZATION
    networks:
     #keycloak_network:
     web:
```

This docker-compose will proxy the whoami container image to localhost/whoami and it works as I expect. Here I expose the whoami container to the public network. However, the point of Traefik (correct me if I'm wrong) is to limit security holes. I would like to only expose 80/443.

I'm trying to get keycloak to work with Traefik, but I get a 404 error. I can get gateway timeout by switching to the internal network, I can verify the keycloak cointainer is running by hitting localhost:8443 (exposing the ports). 
What am I missing? I've tried subdomains keycloak.adwin.usa.northeast.dn and adwin.usa.northeast.dn/keycloak. I've had better luck with /keycloak than I have with subdomains. Is this possible with out dns structure?

```
version: '3'

networks: 
  web: 
    external: true 
  internal-network:
    internal: true

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker --docker.watch --logLevel=DEBUG
    # depends_on:
    #   - omgwtfssl
    networks:
      - web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "5000:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./certs/:/certs/
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
    #labels:
      #- traefik.port=8080
      #- traefik.frontend.rule=Path:/monitor
      #- traefik.protocol=http
      # - traefik.docker.network=web
      # We only need to run this one time to generate our ./cert directory.   
  # omgwtfssl:
  #   image: paulczar/omgwtfssl
  #   volumes:
  #     - "./certs:/certs"
  #   environment:
  #     - SSL_SUBJECT=api.adwin.usa.northeast.dn

  whoami:
     image: containous/whoami # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
     labels:
       - traefik.port=80
       #- traefik.protocol=http
       - traefik.frontend.rule=Path:/whoami
       #- traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.adwin.usa.northeast.dn
       - traefik.docker.network=web
     networks:
      - web

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
        certFile = "/certs/cert.pem"
        keyFile = "/certs/key.pem"

[docker]
domain = "adwin.usa.northeast.dn"
watch = true
#usebindportip = true
```